# Strange behavior of C# Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I have following simplified program

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

class ItemClass {
    public int Id = 0;
    public int[] Childs = new int[] { };
    public int Count = 0;
}

class Class1 {

    Dictionary<int, ItemClass> _Items = new Dictionary<int, ItemClass> { };

    private void AddRecursive(int ItemID, int count, ref Dictionary<int, ItemClass> ItemList) {

        if (!_Items.ContainsKey(ItemID)) {
            return;
        }
        ItemClass _item = _Items[ItemID];
        if (!ItemList.ContainsKey(ItemID)) {
            ItemList.Add(ItemID, _item);
        }
        ItemList[ItemID].Count += count;
        if (_item.Childs.Length > 0) {
            foreach (int tmpItem in _item.Childs) {
                AddRecursive(tmpItem, ItemList[ItemID].Count, ref ItemList);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Add(int item, int[] childs) {
        if (!_Items.ContainsKey(item)) {
            _Items.Add(item, new ItemClass() { Id = item, Childs = childs, Count = 0 });
        }
    }

    public Dictionary<int, ItemClass> MakeList(int ItemID) {
        if (!_Items.ContainsKey(ItemID)) {
            return new Dictionary<int, ItemClass> { };
        }
        Dictionary<int, ItemClass> ItemList = new Dictionary<int, ItemClass> { };
        AddRecursive(ItemID, 1, ref ItemList);
        return ItemList;
    }

}


class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Class1 class1 = new Class1();
        class1.Add(1111, new int[] { });
        class1.Add(2222, new int[] { 1111 });
        class1.Add(3333, new int[] { 1111, 2222 });

        Dictionary<int, ItemClass> items1 = class1.MakeList(3333);
        foreach (ItemClass item in items1.Values) {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Id + "  " + item.Count);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("");

        Dictionary<int, ItemClass> items2 = class1.MakeList(3333);
        foreach (ItemClass item in items2.Values) {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Id + "  " + item.Count);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

It has a simple task of counting items and showing a list of items and their count. When I call the `MakeList` function the first time, results are expected.

Expected:

```
3333  1
1111  2
2222  1

3333  1
1111  2
2222  1
```

Actual

```
3333  1
1111  2
2222  1

3333  2
1111  7
2222  3
```

As I am re-declaring the variable `ItemList`, I'm expecting to see the same result when I call the function for second time, however it is like the results from previous call is cached and re-used.

Why this is happening and why is this behavior?
Is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I see no reason to use `ref ItemList` as parameter of  your `AddRecursive` method. you can just use `ItemList` (without `ref`) and get the same result. That's doesn't seem related to your problem anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is nothing strange with it. You've just modified the value of `Count` property in your `ItemClass` object when you call `AddRecursive` method.

Assuming that you really want to get what you expected, you just need to deep clone your `ItemClass` object or simply create new instance and copy the original value of property.

```
ItemClass _item = new ItemClass() { Childs = _Items[ItemID].Childs, Count = _Items[ItemID].Count, Id = _Items[ItemID].Id };
```

Instead of this

```
Itemclass _item = _Items[ItemId]
```

Comment: I don't know why I thought adding ItemClass to dictionary creates a copy of it! I added a copy method to ItemClass to create a new instance of it.

Answer (score 1):

You re-declaring `ItemList`, but using same objects from internal `_Items` : `ItemClass _item = _Items[ItemID];` and incrementing count on same object. It is why part :). avoid part is to create new items maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you alter the `Count` property of the `ItemClass` instances in the `_Items` dictionary while you run `AddRecursive`.

Get rid of that mutable `Count` property (it really shouldn't be in `ItemClass`), and simplify your code to

```
class ItemClass 
{
    public int Id = 0;
    public int[] Childs = new int[] { };
}

class Class1 
{

    Dictionary<int, ItemClass> _Items = new Dictionary<int, ItemClass>();

    private void AddRecursive(int itemId, Dictionary<int, int> itemList) 
    {

        if (!_Items.ContainsKey(itemId)) 
            return;

        if (!itemList.ContainsKey(itemId)) 
            itemList.Add(itemId, 1);
        else
            itemList[itemId] += 1;

        var item = _Items[itemId];
        if (item.Childs.Length > 0) 
            foreach (int tmpItem in item.Childs)
                AddRecursive(tmpItem, itemList);
    }

    public void Add(int item, int[] childs) 
    {
        if (!_Items.ContainsKey(item)) 
            _Items.Add(item, new ItemClass() { Id = item, Childs = childs });
    }

    public Dictionary<int, int> MakeList(int itemId)
    {
        if (!_Items.ContainsKey(itemId)) 
            return new Dictionary<int, int>();

        var itemList = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        AddRecursive(itemId, itemList);
        return itemList;
    }
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my question,  simplified the program, leaving the issue in it. ItemClass is a class that calculates market value and suggest producing or buying it.